# Push Notification Caveats

Tags: windows-phone-7, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

From what I have read, platform Push Notification services (APNS, GCM and WNS) are free. But is there a caveat (periodic message limits, repeated messages, costs incurred etc). What conditions will I need to handle in my server code to avoid these caveats?

Thank You and I hope my question is "programmatic" enough to be eligible on this forum.

**EDIT:** @Joel agreed. I'll restrict the scope of my question to APNS. Now what are the conditions that I will need to handle?

Comment: I would say your question is appropriately "programmatic", but that you should ask a different question for each service.  They are going to have different rules that govern each one, unrelated from the rest.

Comment: @ameyazing How is APNS / GCM relevant for Windows Phone? And if it's not, why did you pick the tags you did?

Comment: Hi Claus, you are right, tags are incorrect now. My original question was targetting all 3 platforms and looking for information like exceeding notifications limits (if applicable) and similar. Later, as per Joel's suggestion, I narrowed the scope of my question but forgot to modify the tags. Apologies for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

For the Windows Notification Service (WNS), you'll need to handle the [response headers documented on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465435.aspx).

Headers like `dropped` and `channelthrottled` will inform your server that what you're doing is wrong.

See also the [Guidelines and checklist for push notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761462.aspx).